# Filter rows after adding new record in JQgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

the senario is this:
My script adds a new record with "setInterval" function every second:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', id, data, 'first').trigger("reloadGrid");
```

assume while this script is adding new records, user apply some filters but the filter doesn't apply on the new coming records indeed its just work on records that were added before filter action so my grid shows unexpected result.

the key option of my grid:

```
...
datatype: "local",
data: gridData, //a local array
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to me very easy. You do almost all correct, but you should understand that not all jQuery methods returns original jQuery object. For example `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow")` returns the rowid of selected row or `null`, so `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow").trigger("reloadGrid");` would be incorrect.

The method `addRowData` return Boolean value which informs whether the row was successfully added or not. So you have to fix the code to

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("addRowData", id, data, "first");
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

or to

```
var $grid = $("#grid");
$grid.jqGrid("addRowData", id, data, "first");
$grid.trigger("reloadGrid", { current: true });
```

to hold the currently selected row/rows.

Comment: Yeah! that's it.but I've saw a lot sample that they've chained  reloadGrid with addRowData.anyway my problem solved.

Comment: @MasoudSedghi: You are welcome! The most example with `reloadGrid` do it together with `setGridParam` which return `this` and can be changed. One can still find many wrong code examples of cause. In any way it's good that your problem is solved now.